# How to use the navigation bar back button when using a viewbased app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have looked at several tutorials and different posts and can't seem to figure this out. I am simply trying to create a back button to take me back to a view where I was before. In the IB I create the button and link it to my backButton method. However, when I try to use it in the App I can't get it to work. Do I have to push it on the stack first? Any suggestions?

```
-(void)backButton:(id)sender{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Here is the code where I navigate from one view into another: Map is a view I use.

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
int tempButtonTag = selectedButton.tag;
Map *map =[[Map alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
NSMutableString *tempID = [buttonIDArray objectAtIndex:tempButtonTag];
NSMutableString *tempType = [buttonTypeArray objectAtIndex:tempButtonTag];

[map setXmlID:tempID];
[map setXmlType:tempType];

buttonIDArray = nil;
buttonTypeArray = nil;

[buttonIDArray release];
[buttonTypeArray release];


[self presentModalViewController:map animated:YES];



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of `presentModalViewController` is `dismissModalViewController`.

The opposite of `pushViewController` is `popViewController`.

You are mixing these up...

Comment: Yup that was it. Thanks very much!  The solution was -

(void)backButton:(id)sender{
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];


}